# Restore only few views in Eclipse RCP saveAndRestore

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

We have an internal Eclipse RCP application which has only views and no editors.

We make use of the Eclipse saveAndRestore API in our WorkBenchAdvisor to save and restore the workbench state. It works as expected.

We control the display of views based on the User Permissions.

Let us say that there are 2 users to the application; Manager & a Employee. If a Manager logs in, all views will be shown and if an Employee logs in, some of the views will be suppressed. So far so good.

Let us say manager logs in and opens all his views and closes the application. An employee now logs in on the same machine. Now the problem is, since the eclipse restores the workbench state, the views for which the employee does not have privileges is also being restored.

Is there a placeholder provided by eclipse where we can check the user's permission for the views restored and not display those accordingly ?

Please advise as to how to go about solving this issue.

Authentication for the user is done using a Login Dialog opened in the WorkBenchAdvisor.

Eclipse Version used: 3.7

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you persist a view state into memento, store some additional information, about who can see the view. For that override `saveState(IMemento memento)` in your view. After that you can force closing not related views, when everything has been loaded (check out methods in the `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`).

Another possibility would be to throw `PartInitException` in `init` method of your view. This would still open view with an error message, you have provided (like, "No privileges to open this view") instead of the content.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `restorable` flag in the `view` definition in the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point. This allows you to say that the view should never be restored during the start.